# Show join table results even on condition is null

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have five table name **books**,**categories**,**publications**,**author**,**reviews**.

in my app user can review the book after login. so **reviews** table stay empty until user post a review.

**I am trying to run the flowing query in codeigniter model to get book details by category_id and it's working perfect when their review is exist otherwise it's return empty array. this is happening because of this `$this>db>join('reviews','reviews.book_id = books.book_id');` condition return false**

**how can i show result even reviews table on condition is not match?**

```
public function get_book_details($cat_id) {

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('books');
        $this->db->join('categories', 'categories.id = books.category_id');
        $this->db->join('publications', 'publications.id = books.publication_id');
        $this->db->join('author', 'author.id = books.author_id');
        $this->db->join('reviews', 'reviews.book_id = books.book_id');
        $this->db->where('categories.id', $cat_id);

        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

Comment: Hi. Please give desired output for some input. Your description is not clear & you have only given a *wrong* query. And your title doesn't make sense--you don't mean "results when condition is null", you likely mean "book table row data when condition is false". Don't vaguely say "result"; *explain* what is missing. Please read & act on [mcve]. And that's *minimal* so simplify your query. PS JOIN aka INNER JOIN returns all rows that make the condition true that can be made from a row from each table. *LEFT JOIN* returns those rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by nulls.

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEFT JOIN` to get the result if there are no matching associations are found

```
$this->db->join('reviews', 'reviews.book_id = books.book_id','LEFT');
```

Comment: in that case i am not getting some information. like book_id etc.

Comment: @KanonChowdhury you need to provide some sample data set relevant to your table definitions, it would be better if you can add sample schema and some sample data set on http://sqlfiddle.com/ to reproduce the issue you have mentioned